# Azure Container Group Instance

Tags: azure, azure-container-service, azure-container-instances

I am working with Azure Container Instance group.. and one of my containers is constantly restarting.. it goes to a terminated state and restarts. Everything looks good in logs.. The container is running a spring framework + React application. When I run the containers locally.. it works perfectly.

Am not sure what is happening behind the scenes?

Comment: Can you please post the json file so i can have a look. I guess your missing a environmental variable for your container

Comment: +1 to showing your deployment configuration, if it works locally this means some property set for ACI isn't correct causing an exit and perpetual restart if you have the default restartPolicy of "Always".

Comment: Are you sending errors/exceptions to STDOUT? It's possible the error isn't being captured.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Azure CLI to set a **restart policy** of **OnFailure** or **Never**.

```
az container create \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name mycontainer \
    --image mycontainerimage \
    --restart-policy OnFailure
```

If you specify the restart policy and the issue still exists,there might be some problems with the application or script executed in your container. You could use `az container show` command to check the `restartCount` property.

```
az container show --name
                  --resource-group
```

For more details, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting#container-continually-exits-and-restarts).

Comment: When I set the restart policy to **OnFailure** the container runs and then goes to a terminated state and again restarts.. this keeps going on in a loop.

Comment: and when i set the restart policy to **Never** the container gets terminated.

Comment: @Ross What the restartCount property of your container? Perhaps there is a issue with your application or script executed in the container.

Comment: I have the same problem. The container is killed off as soon as it starts even if my restart policy is onfailure