# Azure Container Instance is immediately killed on Startup

Tags: azure-container-instances

I am trying to run an azure container instance but it appears to be getting killed off the second I run it. This works fine in 2 other resource groups but not my production resource group where I see the following:

- In events I see 'Successfully pulled image
  selenium/standalone-chrome:latest' with count 1 and then 'Started
  container' and then 'Killing container' with count 31. The times for
  started and killed are the same.
- In logs, it just says 'No logs available'
- The metrics for CPU and memory on the container never show any change from zero.

Looked at this article but the proposed solution didn't work: [Azure Container Group Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49544077/azure-container-group-instance) I have tried putting on both an empty directory volume and 2Gb of ram as advised here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium but nothing works.

This is the code I am using to create the container:

```
containerGroup = await azure.ContainerGroups.Define(containerName)
            .WithRegion("West Europe")
            .WithExistingResourceGroup(configuration.ContainerResourceGroup)
            .WithLinux()
            .WithPublicImageRegistryOnly()
            .WithEmptyDirectoryVolume("devshm")
            .DefineContainerInstance(containerName)
                .WithImage("selenium/standalone-chrome")
                .WithExternalTcpPorts(4444)
                .WithVolumeMountSetting("devshm", "/dev/shm")
                .WithMemorySizeInGB(2)
                .Attach()
            .WithDnsPrefix(configuration.AppServiceName + "container")
            .WithRestartPolicy(ContainerGroupRestartPolicy.OnFailure)
            .CreateAsync(cancellationToken);
```

How do I debug what is going wrong?
What is wrong with the container?

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps someone I renamed the "containerName" parameter in the above example from myinstance to myinstance1 and changed the region from West Europe to UK South. This fixed the issue. I can only think that Azure caches instances somehow to reduce start up times and the cached image I was using was poisoned somehow.

Answer (score 0):

One issue could be the restart policy - have a look at the Microsoft restart policy troubleshooting on [Microsoft's ACI troubleshooting page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Support). According to the website under the **Container continually exits and restarts (no long-running process)** header in the page:

> Container groups default to a restart policy of Always, so containers
> in the container group always restart after they run to completion.
> You may need to change this to OnFailure or Never if you intend to run
> task-based containers. If you specify OnFailure and still see
> continual restarts, there might be an issue with the application or
> script executed in your container.

In your case you may need to adjust the code as follows using the withStartingCommand:

```
containerGroup = await azure.ContainerGroups.Define(containerName)
            .WithRegion("West Europe")
            .WithExistingResourceGroup(configuration.ContainerResourceGroup)
            .WithLinux()
            .WithPublicImageRegistryOnly()
            .WithEmptyDirectoryVolume("devshm")
            .DefineContainerInstance(containerName)
                .WithImage("selenium/standalone-chrome")
                .WithExternalTcpPorts(4444)
                .WithVolumeMountSetting("devshm", "/dev/shm")
                .WithMemorySizeInGB(2)
                .WithStartingCommandLine("tail")
                .WithStartingCommandLine("-f")
                .WithStartingCommandLine("/dev/null")
                .Attach()
            .WithDnsPrefix(configuration.AppServiceName + "container")
            .WithRestartPolicy(ContainerGroupRestartPolicy.OnFailure)
            .CreateAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also do consider that if you are building the Docker image using a Macbook with M1 / M2, this might be the cause for failure.

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/74945351/3047500 for more info.

TLDR; when building/pushing on Macbook M1/M2's use `--platform`:

```
docker build -t your-image-tag --platform linux/amd64 .
```

Cheers.

Comment: FYI the OP solved this on their own, 3 years ago. The question should be closed at this point. Also, fyi - this really isn't on-topic here, as it's not a programming question.

Answer (score -1):

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting#container-continually-exits-and-restarts-no-long-running-process) is helpful for this issue.

```
--command-line
    linux   => "tail -f /dev/null"  
    windows => "ping -t localhost"

# .yml
command: tail -f /dev/null
```

It will keep your azure instance running.
As now azure do have a endpoint to connect/analyze the process on.