# Docker - How to build image for M1 Mac or AMD conditionally from Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, build, dockerfile

Some context:
-I'm a `Docker` newbie (on it since 1 day),
-I've got a small `VM` running `linux/AMD` and I own a M1 Mac (`ARM`),
-I'd like to also use Container for Dev (instead of virtual env).

For building my container for `prod`, being on a M1 Mac, I have the below `Dockerfile`:
See the `--platform=linux/amd64` arg in `FROM` and It works (= I'm able to deploy).

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.10-slim-bullseye
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV FLASK_ENV=development 
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

However, how can I say in my `Dockerfile` to not use `--platform=linux/amd64` **if** I want to build for local dev?
I've seen some post on SO with conditions in `dockerfile` **but only** for `RUN` command.
Any idea or best practices?
Thanks.

Comment: Your MacOS host ships with Python already; if this is for day-to-day development, why not just use that (with a virtual environment, without Docker)?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm trying a new stack (Python/Flask + server-side `Sqlite` + `VM`, instead of my usual NodeJS/Express, Google App Engine, Firestore). It sounds - at first - cool to run a container with mounted volume with `SQlite` locally before deploying the very same containers in prod.

Comment: I might avoid SQLite in Docker, in favor of a stateless application container paired with a relational database like PostgreSQL in a separate container.  There are a lot of complexities around trying to do development inside Docker proper, but I've generally found it straightforward to build an application on the host and then use the language-standard packaging tools (_e.g._, Pip) to build that application into an immutable Docker image.

Comment: You're certainly right and more experimented than me. However, in a way, I try to mimic `fly.io` stack (docker/SQLite & Cie). Furthermore, I didn't find a "simple" way to dev locally in Sqlite and then deploy; Docker seems to allow to "test prod locally".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can use the `--platform` parameter on [docker buildx build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#platform) or [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options) to set platform(s) to build the image which will be used within any `FROM` calls within the `Dockerfile` if nothing else is specified (see [Dockerfile FROM](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from)), as mentioned in the documentation.

You can then use the [TARGETPLATFORM](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#automatic-platform-args-in-the-global-scope) variable within your `Dockerfile` to get what platform it's being built for if needed. If you want to change the default platform to build for, you can set the [DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#environment-variables) environment variable.

Comment: Thanks. `docker build --platform linux/amd64` saves my day.  
I can also use a variable in my `makefile` (ex: `docker build --platform ${ARCH}`)

Answer (score 1):

I would either

- not specify the platform in the Dockerfile, and build it the platform-specific way locally (or for production by speciying the build step in the CI) with this command for M1 mac: `docker buildx build --platform=linux/arm64 -t myTag .`, or
- have two separate Dockerfiles (such es `Dockerfile.intel`, and `Dockerfile`), with the respective platform defined in them. This way, any build pipeline will pick `Dockerfile` as default, but for local build, you can specify which one to use, like so: `docker build -f Dockerfile.intel .`

To run your image as a dev conteiner, specify the image in a `devcontainer.json`, and start + attach by typing `Reopen in Container` in the command palette in VSCode.

Comment: think you meant amd64

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time researching this myself - quite frustrated that builds on my Mac were taking so long.

- You should *not* have two Dockerfiles - but a single multi-arch capable Dockerfile.
- Use `tonistiigi/xx` in a multi-stage build if you want fast build times and no arch specific settings.
- I use a Golang project as an example but it will apply to any Dockerfile.

#### Method 1 - use `buildx` QEMU

If you have a "regular" Dockerfile - i.e. you don't have a `--platform` statement in there or anything archtitecture specific, you can probably just do:

```
docker buildx build -f Dockerfile --platform linux/amd64 --tag my-container:latest --load .
```

This will use QEMU - but it is *slow* and it sometimes breaks (compiler switches, etc). That's because the build itself is run in an emulator (in this case emulating `amd64`)

#### Method 2: Roll your own mulit-arch image:

If you had a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM golang:1.20

ADD app /app
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0
RUN cd /app && go build -o app .
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/app" ]
```

Make it this:

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM golang:1.20 AS build
# get gcc cross toolchain
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install g++-x86-64-linux-gnu libc6-dev-amd64-cross
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y clean

ADD app /app
ARG TARGETOS TARGETARCH
ENV CGO_ENABLED=1
WORKDIR /app
# RUN gcc -dumpmachine with --progress=plain here to see what gcc is used by default
RUN CC=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc GOOS=$TARGETOS GOARCH=$TARGETARCH go build -o app .
ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/app" ]
```

Notice we have to install a specific cross toolchain for the architecture we need. This is not ideal - since it make our Dockerfile arch specific :/

#### Method 3: Use the [tonistiigi/xx tools](https://github.com/tonistiigi/xx) Docker layer

Instead we can use this `tonistiigi/xx` package as a base layer. It provides tools which make cross builds way easier and still running native.

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM tonistiigi/xx AS xx
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM golang:1.20

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install build-essential
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y clean

COPY --from=xx / /
ADD app /app
ARG TARGETPLATFORM
RUN xx-apt install -y libc6-dev gcc
ENV CGO_ENABLED=1
WORKDIR /app
RUN xx-go --wrap
RUN go build -o app . && xx-verify app
ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/app" ]
```

The `xx-` tools provide wrappers which understand the Docker multiplatform variables and then use the right cross toolchain to build the correct `TARGETARCH` architecture package.

This is the best way - it produce fast native, cross builds regardless of where you run the `docker build buildx` command. And it should work on Docker Desktop or docker installed on Linux as well - `aarch64` or `amd64` alike.

The same build command:

```
docker buildx build -f Dockerfile --platform linux/amd64 --tag my-container:latest --load .
```

is used for all three methods.

To the OP - this means they could run the command on Docker Desktop (MacOS side) or using docker installed in their Linux VM.

Check out my blog post:

https://www.izumanetworks.com/blog/build-docker-on-apple-m/

for more details.